# Flask SocketIO: Error during WebSocket handshake

Tags: flask, websocket, flask-socketio

I am trying to establish a websocket communication using Flask-SocketIO, but I keep getting "Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400" in my browser's console.

I am using Chromium browser on Raspbian OS.

I have eventlet installed.

Here is the code of myapp.py:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
io = SocketIO(app)

clients = []

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index2.html')

@io.on('connected')
def connected():
    clients.append(request.sid)
    print("client connected")
    print(request.sid)

@io.on('disconnect')
def disconnect():
    clients.remove(request.sid)
    print("client disconnected")
    print(request.sid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    io.run(app, host='localhost', port=5000)
```

And this is index2.html:

```
<html>
<br>

<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js" integrity="sha256-yr4fRk/GU1ehYJPAs8P4JlTgu0Hdsp4ZKrx8bDEDC3I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<br>

<body>

   <h2>HELLO</h2>

   <script>

      $("document").ready(function(){

         var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');

         socket.on('connect', function() {
            socket.emit('connected');
         });

      });

   </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I run the application with command

```
python myapp.py
```

When I navigate to http://localhost:5000, I can see "HELLO" on the webpage, but I do not get the "client connected" message and in the browser's console, there is the error message "Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400".

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is rejecting the connection, for some reason. What you can do is enable detailed logging in the server:

```py
io = SocketIO(app, engineio_logger=True, logger=True)
```

And then each time there is a 400 error you will see some additional information about the error.

A very likely cause of these 400s is a cross-origin validation that failed. It is not the only possible cause, by the most common with web browser clients. If this is the case, you will need to add the `cors_allowed_origins` option to your Socket.IO server.